# How to get recent sales from Square API?

Tags: square

I'm a developer and am new to Square.

We are going to enter sales into the Square app on iPads and I have to send the sales and payment information automatically and asap to NetSuite (a cloud ERP system)

1. I'm reading the API docs and can't see a way to run some code when a sales 
   order is created. Is there a way?
2. If the answer to 1 is no then which part of the API can I call periodically to request a list of all sales orders since the last time I asked?

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked into using [webhooks](https://docs.connect.squareup.com/webhooks) to be notified when a transaction takes place? Once you receive a notification from the webhook you can then call the appropriate endpoint to get the information you want to send to NetSuite.

Comment: What should I call when I receive a notification from the webhook? I can't see anything that gives me a list of recent orders unless I already have order IDs.

Comment: Once you receive the entity_id you can call the [Retrieve Payments](https://docs.connect.squareup.com/api/connect/v1#get-paymentid) endpoint which will give you an itemized breakdown of the transaction.